# Differentiate between null and undefined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a GraphQL API project where user is able to update an entire article or portions of it.

Usually, I just send JSON with columns I want to update and it works flawlessly for these columns, the json is as follows:

```
{
    title: "New title",
    categoryId: 3
}
```

But here's the issue: any other column that I didn't provide in this json becomes a `null` and simply adding:

```
if(value == null) 
    -- don't update that column
```

Wouldn't work with columns that **can be nullable**, because there's no difference between sending:

```
{
    title: "New title",
    categoryId: 3
}
```

and sending

```
{
    title: "New title",
    categoryId: 3,
    someCol: null
}
```

Even though in first JSON I want the value to remain unchanged and in second JSON I want it to be set to null.

So, my question is - how can I handle it in EFCore?

Comment: http://jsonpatch.com/

Comment: @madreflection wouldn't work in my case, I'm actually using GraphQL and HotChocolate.io but it was simpler to explain in REST

Comment: I suggest asking exactly what you need, because this has nothing to do with C# or EF Core, and I'm about to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same situation and we've gone with: null = don't change, anything else = change to value.

```
var entity = ReadEntity();

if(jsonInput.Field1 != null)
{
    entity.Field1 = jsonInput.Field1;
}
```

This means that you can never 'unset' a field in the entity, but for us, that is acceptable.   `null` = uninitialise, once it's initialised, it can't be 'uninitialised', only set to another value (including 'default').